# Autowired Spring NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, web-services, webservices-client

I have a problem with my code trying to generate @Autowired.

The Class:

```
public class ConsultasMDMWSClientImpl implements ConsultasMDMWSClient {

    @Autowired
    ConsultasMDMWSPortype consultasMDMWSPortype;
    public ConsultarClienteResponseMDM consultarClienteEnMdm(ConsultarClienteRequest clienteReq) {

       ConsultarClienteResponseMDM response = new ConsultarClienteResponseMDM();
       ConsultasMDMWSService consultasMDMWSService = new ConsultasMDMWSService();

       ConsultarClienteResponse clienteResp = null;
       clienteResp = consultasMDMWSPortype.consultarCliente(clienteReq);
       ListaCursoresMDM listaCursores;
            listaCursores = new ObjectMapper().readValue(clienteResp.getListaCursoresResponse(), ListaCursoresMDM.class);

       response.getListaCursoresResponse().add(listaCursores);
    return response;
    }
 }
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
      <context:annotation-config/>
      <context:component-scan base-package="pe.com.claro.eai.esb.ws.jira.mdm"/>
      <import resource="wsclients-config.xml"/>
```

My wsclients-config.xml

```
 <bean id="consultasMDMWSPortype" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
           <property name="serviceInterface" value="pe.com.claro.eai.consultasmdmws.ConsultasMDMWSPortype"/>    
           <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://limdeseaiv28.tim.com.pe:8909/ConsultasMDMWS/ConsultasMDMPortSB11?wsdl"/>
           <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://eai.claro.com.pe/ConsultasMDMWS"/>
           <property name="serviceName" value="ConsultasMDMWSService"/>
           <property name="portName" value="ConsultasMDMPortSB11"/>
           <property name="lookupServiceOnStartup" value="false"/>
      </bean>

        <bean id="consultasMDMWSClient"
            class="pe.com.claro.eai.esb.ws.jira.mdm.service.client.ConsultasMDMWSClientImpl">
                <property name="consultasMDMWSPortype" ref="consultasMDMWSPortype"/>
       </bean>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've mapped everything like an example of my work
I'm new on Spring, my web method works without Spring.

The error just appear when I use @Autowired.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thaks everyone.

Comment: Could you add code where you create and access ConsultasMDMWSClientImpl? My guess is that you don't use the bean but create the instance yourself...

Comment: You're both Autowiring your reference and setting it in your xml: <property name="consultasMDMWSPortype" ref="consultasMDMWSPortype"/>   @Autowired
    ConsultasMDMWSPortype consultasMDMWSPortype;

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to solution proposed by @Christopher, if you want to keep the "old-style" XML configuration injection (setter injection) you need to remove `@Autowired` annotation and declare a setter to ConsultasMDMWSPortype, ie:

```
ConsultasMDMWSPortype consultasMDMWSPortype;
```

and

```
public ConsultasMDMWSPortype setConsultasMDMWSPortype(ConsultasMDMWSPortype consultasMDMWSPortype) {
    this.consultasMDMWSPortype = consultasMDMWSPortype;
}
```

So spring will be able to wire the ref-bean configured in xml, through the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `@Component` annotation on top of `ConsultasMDMWSClientImpl` class.

Like:

```
@Component
public class ConsultasMDMWSClientImpl implements ConsultasMDMWSClient {
```

This is needed to indicate that this is a spring bean, so that the spring container scan it and initialize as a spring bean while starting the spring container.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It's not neccesary, because `ConsultasMDMWSClientImpl` is already defined in XML, though it's a weird mixture of xml/annotation configuration and he is wiring twice `consultasMDMWSClient`

Comment: Ohh s*it I simply overlook it. Thanks for advice. // Actually this makes @Autowired redundant because property consultasMDMWSPortype has been alredy set in XML. So in this case null value should not expected here. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you're mixing XML wiring with annotation wiring. The simplest solution is to take away the @Autowired of the Portype and instead inject ConsultasMDMWSClient in other beans:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  ConsultasMDMWSClient client;

}
```

Another solution would be remove the wiring in XML and just inject portype in your client:

```
@Component
public class ConsultasMDMWSClientImpl implements ConsultasMDMWSClient {

  @Resource
  protected ConsultasMDMWSPortype consultasMDMWSPortype;

}
```

Once again, you inject the client in other beans.

In any case, you shouldn't be hardwiring the JAX-WS settings in literals, you should replace them with values in properties files and prepare different properties files for different environments. For example:

```
<bean id="consultasMDMWSPortype" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
     <property name="serviceInterface" value="${jaxws.serviceInterface}"/>    
     <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="${jaxws.wsdlDocumentUrl"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced @Autowired by @Qualifier.

Thanks for the help.